# Magento2 - How to fill a dropdown from backend configuration [Solved]

Tags: magento2, admin, layout, backend, forms

I'm making a custom form with some dropdown data a user can select.

The content which get's inserted needs to come from the **backend configuration**.

This is the form I have made, **this form will be shown on the frontend, not the backend.**

[image]

I have no idea how to insert data in the **dropdown** above from the **admin backend**, this is the **adminhtml** I've already created:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="tab"
             translate="label"
             sortOrder="1000">
            <label>UT</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="trendsquare_module"
                 translate="label"
                 type="text"
                 sortOrder="1"
                 showInDefault="1"
                 showInWebsite="1"
                 showInStore="1">
            <label>Module settings</label>
            <tab>tab</tab>
            <resource>AdminTabs::config</resource>
            <group id="trendsquare_module"
                   translate="label"
                   type="text"
                   sortOrder="2"
                   showInDefault="1"
                   showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="1">
                <label>Dropdown Data</label>
                <field id="dropdown" translate="label" type="editablemultiselect" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Dropdown Data</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Which gives me this as a result:

[image]

Comment: let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to populate the dropdown on the frontend according to the backend configuration.

First you need to create a tab in the admin configuration like this:
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="tab"
             translate="label"
             sortOrder="1000">
            <label>Your tab label</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="AdminTabs"
                 translate="label"
                 type="text"
                 sortOrder="1"
                 showInDefault="1"
                 showInWebsite="1"
                 showInStore="1">
            <label>ReCaptcha settings</label>
            <tab>tab</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::config</resource>
            <group id="general"
                   translate="label"
                   type="text"
                   sortOrder="1"
                   showInDefault="1"
                   showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="1">
                <label>Your child tab label</label>
                <field id="dropdown" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="7" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Dropdown values</label>
                    <comment>Data needs to be separated with a ; (semicolon).</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

If you would like to have a default value for the dropdown field you can do that with the config.xml which gets called with `<resource>`.

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <AdminTabs>
            <general>
                <dropdown>i.e: 01-01-2000 11:00; 01-01-2001 11:00</dropdown>
            </general>
        </AdminTabs>
    </default>
</config>
```

Now you have created the admin configuration tab with a text field. (And maybe a default value)

Next thing to do is create a function in your block.
/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Form.php

```
    /**
     * Retrieve dropdown data
     */
    public function getDropdownData()
    {
        $content = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('AdminTabs/general/dropdown');
        $lines = explode(";", $content);
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            $line = trim($line);
            if (!empty($line)) {
                echo '<option value="' . $line . '">' . $line . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Above function returns option tags with the values which are set in the admin configuration.

Here is an example to use the function in your template file.
/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
<select required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>- Label -*</option>
    <?php echo $block->getDropdownData(); ?>
</select>
```

Result:
[image]

I hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 2):

Add dropdown `<source_model>` in field like this

```
<field id="dropdown" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="7" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Your Label</label>
    <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Myoptions</source_model>
</field>
```

Now create **Myoptions.php** at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Config/Myoptions.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config;

class Myoptions implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{   
    protected $modelFactory;

    public function __construct(modelFactory $modelFactory)
    {
        $this->modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $collection = $this->modelFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $options = [];
        foreach ($collection as $value) {
            $options[] = ['label' => $value->getName(), 'value'=>$value->getId()];
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but the values and labels are now static. These values need to be filled with the data provided in the backend configuration.

Comment: @FrankGroot check my updated answer. you can load your model in construct and get option dynamically

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, the values and labels in the dropdown need to be set in the admin configuration. I feel like they stay static when i insert them with a model...

Comment: For that add data in dropdown like `option1,option2,option3`. then use explode function and fill option with foreach

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but the dropdown will be shown in a form on the frontend. The data which needs to be in the dropdown comes from the backend.. If I fully understand your suggestion above there will be a dropdown added in the backend...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Source Model for this to work:

```
<field id="dropdown" translate="label" type="editablemultiselect" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <label>Dropdown Data</label>
    <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Example</source_model>
</field>
```

Your source model needs to implement `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\SourceInterface`

```
class Example implements \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\SourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Example constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $content = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('path/to/config');

        $values = [];
        $lines = explode("\n", $content);
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            $line = trim($line);
            if (!empty($line)) {
                $values[] = [
                    'value' => $line,
                    'label' => $line
                ];
            }
        }

        return $values;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but the values and labels are now static. These values need to be filled with the data provided in the backend configuration.

Comment: No problem. I've updated my answer to reflect your use case.

Comment: Thank you Giel, after i tested your code i got this error `Call to undefined method Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\DropdownOptions::toOptionArray()` I renamed the class from Example to DropdownOptions